# How to only display Second level of menus in Superfish?

Tags: navigation

I am using Superfish to display the menus in the left sidebar. I am using the Main Menu navigation structure which only displays the top/first level. In the sidebar, I would like to display only the second level menus. But I cannot figure out how to do this.

At the moment, the complete menu is being displayed...

PS. the reason I am using superfish is because I need the sidebar menu to be able to slide out/drop down menu items.

I have extracted https://github.com/mehrpadin/Superfish-for-Drupal/archive/1.x.zip to sites/all/libraries/superfish I have extracted http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/superfish-7.x-1.9.zip to sites/all/modules/superfish I have extracted ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/libraries-7.x-2.1.zip to sites/all/modules/libraries

My superfish menu parent is set to Main menu, Menu depth is set to 2 and Path levels is set to 1.

However, the superfish menu in the sidebar is always the same, regardles of what level of the menu I am in :(

Answer (score 1):

Hit 'configure block' on your superfish menu block. Under 'Menu depth' make your desired changes. This sets number of child levels starting with the parent selected above. -1 means all of them, 0 means none of them. (Default: -1)

Comment: Thanks for that @Nigel-waters
I tried that, but the entire (top level) menu is displayed regardless what page I am on :(

Comment: It works without issue for me. Try flushing cache. Make sure you have the latest library release. Not sure what else.

Comment: Thanks for that @Nigel-waters
I've updated everything, but still seeing the Main Menu on all pages regardless of the level...

In the superfish settings, I've bot <Main menu> selected. Is this ok? I mean this is the menu I want displayed... but would like the menu to only display the parent leve of the page not EVERYTHING.

I've also selected the Menu Depth to 1 and Path levels to one.

Comment: I have extracted https://github.com/mehrpadin/Superfish-for-Drupal/archive/1.x.zip to sites/all/libraries/superfish I have extracted http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/superfish-7.x-1.9.zip to sites/all/modules/superfish I have extracted ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/libraries-7.x-2.1.zip to sites/all/modules/libraries

My superfish menu parent is set to Main menu, Menu depth is set to 2 and Path levels is set to 1.

However, the superfish menu in the sidebar is always the same, regardles of what level of the menu I am in :(

@nigel-waters

Comment: I am not sure what else to try. It works for me without issues. Maybe someone else has some ideas?